# Memory coalescence analysis in llvm

Tags: c++, llvm, static-analysis, llvm-ir

I'm trying to perform coalescing analysis on a program using LLVM analysis passes.

Basically, I need to look at array accesses and figure out if the memory accesses can be coalesced, i.e, if the access expression is monotonic with respect to the induction variable.

I'm facing the following problem. Array accesses are expressed in terms of getelementptr instruction in LLVM IR. How can I reconstruct the expression from there?

If it is not possible using static analysis, I'm open to performing dynamic analysis too.

If it helps, I'm trying to implement the following algorithm:

```
procedure getCoalescingFactor(f, warpSize, reqLineSize)
    x ← the variable that corresponds to the x grid coordinate
    fw ← f where all variables are fixed except x grid coordinate
    mono ← monotonicity(fw , x)
    if mono is unknown then
        culprits ← variables in fw which do not have a sign
        fw ← fw where each variable in culprits is assumed positive
        mono ← monotonicity(fw , x)
    end if
    if mono is monotonic then
        if mono is increasing then
            size ← f (x + warpSize) − f (x)
        else
            size ← f (x) − f (x + warpSize)
        end if
        return reqLineSize
    else
       offsets ← [fw (x), fw (x + 1), . . . , fw (x + warpSize)]
       uniqOffsets ← removeDuplicates(offsets)
       return size(uniqOffsets)
    end if
end procedure
```